# Notice: Undefined index: log

Tags: php

I am having problems logging in to php. is says Notice: Undefined index: log in.. i tried fixing it on my own but it just got worst T_T please help me guys

here is the line that is having an error

```
>$user = $_SESSION['log']['username'];
```

here is the whole code 
>

```
<?php
include("session/DBConnection.php");

$user = $_SESSION['log']['username'];
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = '$user'") or die (mysql_error()); 
            $display = mysql_fetch_array($query);   ?>
```

Comment: So where's the code that sets the session variable `log`?

Comment: If ($numberOfRows == 0) 
    {
    echo " <font color= 'red'>Invalid username and password!    </font>";
    }
    else if ($numberOfRows > 0) 
    {
    (isset($_SESSION['is']));
    $_SESSION['log']['login']    = TRUE;
    $_SESSION['log']['username'] = $_POST['username'];
    $session = "1"; 
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE username =     '$username'") or die (mysql_error()); 
    $display = mysql_fetch_array($query);

Answer (score 1):

change this to:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['log']['username'])) { // add this IF statement to check the variable is set or not
   $user = $_SESSION['log']['username'];
   $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = '$user'") or die (mysql_error()); 
   $display = mysql_fetch_array($query);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably because `$_SESSION['log']['username'];` is empty.

Add line for testing it, example:

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['log']['username']))
    {
     //your sql query
     ....

    }
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say `empty`? Does `""` (an empty string) fits your "empty" term definition?

Comment: yes, so $user values is empty too. Maybe you can show use in your code when you declare your $_SESSION variable (not in comments)

Comment: 1. Om not an OP 2. If there is an empty string there - there will be no undefined index notice